# Scala, Akka Http, Heroku in sbt multi-project

Tags: scala, heroku, akka-http

I'm starting with Heroku, I'm a developer that build Rest API using Scala and Akka Http.

Yesterday I was able to create a very simple API and deploy it in Heroku. To do I followed this example: https://dzone.com/articles/akka-http-from-zero-to-heroku-in-10-minutes

Then I decide to add complexity to the API so I created a new project: an sbt multi-project. Usually I do pretty much what is described in this example: https://pbassiner.github.io/blog/defining_multi-project_builds_with_sbt.html. The code of this project is located here: https://github.com/ovats/heroku-akka-multi.

In my local environment the project works fine. I start the service with:

```
sbt api/run
```

Then using curl I can make a request:

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

So far so good.

The problem is: I can deploy it to Heroku (`git push heroku master`) but it wont run.
Using the `heroku cli` I can see in the logs:

```
...
2021-11-27T01:06:44.368868+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/heroku-akka-multi`
2021-11-27T01:06:46.211834+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-11-27T01:06:46.211994+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: target/universal/stage/bin/heroku-akka-multi: No such file or directory
2021-11-27T01:06:46.339690+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-11-27T01:06:46.472410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-11-27T01:06:46.475832+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
...
```

Ok, I can see `bash: target/universal/stage/bin/heroku-akka-multi: No such file or directory`. I think this is related to the content of the file `Procfile`.

Is the problem the `Procfile` content?
Is the issue somewhere else?
It seems that Heroku does not know how to start the service, maybe where is the `main` class or something similar to this. What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The thing is with SBT multi projects, the generated files needed by Herolu to run are not in the expected directory as your error message states. I don't know Herolu but you probably have a config somewhere to change the path used for looking for binaries. And/or you can look at sbt-native-packager to adapt the sbt generated files.

Comment: If you have more complex builds (or if you like to follow the good rule of separating build and deployment) you can consider [native-packager with docker image](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) and [deploying docker image](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker).

Comment: Thank you Mateusz Kubuszok, I will go for that approach.